# On Solaris, how can I tell what processes are doing disk i/o on a particular device?

Tags: solaris, io

On Solaris, *iostat* tells me that a device is 92% busy, but how do I find out what programs are making the requests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean Solaris 10 try `iotop`, a DTrace script by Brendan Gregg. It lists the device (fifth column).

http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/iotop

You can find some other particularly useful DTrace scripts at http://prefetch.net/articles/solaris.dtracetopten.html.

Comment: iotop is also part of the [DTrace Toolkit](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+dtrace/dtracetoolkit)

Comment: I tried it, but alas my login is insufficiently privileged.